# Reading from message queue (non-blocking if empty)

Tags: c, linux, message-queue, sysv-ipc

I'm writing to message queue

```
if (msgsnd(q, &msg, sizeof(message), slaves_list[to]) == -1)
```

and reading

```
if (msgrcv(q, &msg, sizeof(message), id, 0) == -1)
```

but what if this queue is empty? How to check that? If there is nothing I want execute next instruction in the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IPC_NOWAIT`. From the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/msgrcv.html):

> If `(msgflg & IPC_NOWAIT)` is non-zero, the calling thread will return immediately with a return value of `-1` and errno set to `[ENOMSG]`.

Answer (score 4):

Use IPC_NOWAIT for msgflg parameter: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgsnd.2.html

IPC_NOWAIT
Return immediately if no message of the requested type is in the queue.  The system call fails with errno set to ENOMSG.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if queue is empty using the

```
ipcs
```

command in linux terminal.

It will show you the queues that you have created.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but please note that the OP is asking about `C` programming, so that shelling out to an external utility is likely not an option.